# SQL Server tables extend to many tables

Tags: sql-server, database, client, extend

I'm handling this problem here in company: We have different customers, that need different fields in the same table, but we do not want to have a table with 300 columns, which is inneficient, hard to use and so on. Example:

table_products have this fields: product_id, product_name, product_cost.

then, the first client 'X' needs the field product_registerid.
the client 'Y' needs the field product_zipareaid.

That happens by different causes. Example: they are from different states, that have different rules.

At this moment we came up with this solution, which i don't like: 
product_id, product_name, product_cost, product_personal. In this product_personal we have saved values like '{product_registerid:001;product_zipareaid:001-000131}'.

I came up with a theoretic solution: extend the table, and the sql will know when i do a query in the extended table, and shou me the column with the main table's column. Something like:

table_products with columns product_id, product_name, product_cost.
table_products_x with column product_registerid.
table_products_y with column product_zipareaid.

And the querys would return:

1.
select * from table_products where product_registerid = 001:
product_id, product_name, product_cost, product_registerid
1, iphone, 599, 001.

2.
select * from table_products where product_zipareaid = 000-000110:
product_id, product_name, product_cost, product_zipareaid
1, iphone, 599, 000-000110.

So, im accepting different suggestions for solving our problem.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add a single `Extended Properties` table, that would look something like this:

```
Product_id  (FK)
Client_id
PropertyName
PropertyValue
```

And so it would be populated with values like:

```
Product_id Client_id  PropertyName         PropertyValue
1          x          product_registerid   001
1          y          product_zipareaid    000-000110
```

Then you just join table_products to Extended_properties on Product_Id and put the Client_id(s) you want in the WHERE clause.

Note that you'll probably end up wanting to use a PIVOT query to get multiple extended properties for each client.

Comment: In the case i want property to be of different types, like blob, int, varchar. What you suggest? Also, i would like to delivery easy of use for my .net developers, that are using modeling based with linq, so they can do something like db.table_products.product_zipareaid = 000-000102. Thank you.

Comment: For anything other than blobs, you can just use varchar or nvarchar, which can be cast to numeric at query time.   If you really need blob properties, you should keep those in their own table, similar to this one, but PropertyValue would be a blob type.   I am not an expert on linq so I don't know what limitations it has.